# Module Upgrade Issue

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade

I have created db schema and also write the code for upgrade schema.
Also changed the version in module.xml file.

After that i am running this comman "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" and running cache clean command but still my changes not getting update.

Also removed the folder from generated folder.

Is there anything else i have to do so get the changes?

Comment: you need to generate whitelist first specify vendor and modlename: 
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module

Comment: I have run this above command but still its not working, My modules name showing in module list and config file but its not showing in DB "setup_module" table.

Comment: Then the issue is in module, check module.xml and registration.php